# Adding Lines to a Central Point (Lat/Long) in R / ggplot

Tags: r, ggplot2, latitude-longitude

I have some data that is Lat/Long for guests to an event (I have added the data below, just the first few lines but my df is larger).

```
Name, n, Town, State, Country, Lat, Long
Bob, 5, Dundee, n/a, Scotland, 56.462018, -2.970721
Bob, 1, Forfar, n/a, Scotland, 56.643558, -2.889062
Jefferson, 1, Inverness, n/a, Scotland, 57.477773, -4.224721
Dave, 2, London, n/a, England, 51.507351, -0.127758
Randy, 2, Dublin, n/a, Ireland, 53.349805, -6.260310
Buck, 2, Landing, NJ, USA, 40.905411, -74.665695
John, 2, Randolph, NJ, USA, 40.847806, -74.574725
Frank, 1, Morris Plains, NJ, USA, 40.839592, -74.481870
Jimmy, 1, Henryville, PA, USA, 41.093703, -75.241293
Mike, 1, Cliffside Park, NJ, USA, 40.821489, -73.987639
Spence, 1, North Bergen, NJ, USA, 40.804267, -74.012084
Jimmy, 1, West New York, NJ, USA, 40.787879, -74.014306
Jerry, 2, North Bergen, NJ, USA, 40.804267, -74.012084
Dingle, 1, North Bergen, NJ, USA, 40.804267, -74.012084
```

Then I have the Lat/Long of the event location:

```
lat<-40.853988
long<--74.829055
```

What I would like to do is plot all the points for the guests as a scatterplot and then have a single line go from each of the guest points to the event location.

Getting the Scatter is simple:

```
### Copy Data from above to Clipboard
event<-read.table(file = "clipboard", sep = ",", header=TRUE)
ggplot(event, aes(x=Long, y=Lat)) + 
  geom_point(color="darkred", size=2, alpha=.3) + 
  geom_point(aes(x=long, y=lat), color="blue", size=3)
```

Now, is there a way to have a line come from each guest point (red points) to the event location (blue point)?

I tried geom_path() but this systematically adds a line from point-to-point.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `geom_segment`. First add the destination lat/long to the database

```
lat<-40.853988
long<--74.829055
event$lat1 <- lat
event$long1 <- long

ggplot(event, aes(x=Long, y=Lat)) + 
  geom_point(color="darkred", size=2, alpha=.3) + 
  geom_point(aes(x=long, y=lat), color="blue", size=3) +
  geom_segment(aes(xend = long1, yend = lat1))
```

Answer (score 0):

How about something like this. What it does is simulate the structure for geom_path for different groups, where each group is a point from the original df

```
require(dplyr)
require(ggplot2)
EventCoords <- event %>% mutate(Lat=lat, Long=long,order=2,group=1:nrow(event))
event <- event %>% mutate(group=1:nrow(.),order=1) %>% rbind(EventCoords)
P1 <- ggplot(event, aes(x=Long, y=Lat)) +
     geom_point(color="darkred", size=2, alpha=.3) +
     geom_point(aes(x=long, y=lat), color="blue", size=3)
P1 <- P1 + geom_path(aes(group=group))
```

[image]